# Filtering on fields doesn't apply the actual fitler set

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-apiv2

Extending the [BaseAPIEndpoint](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/api/v2/endpoints.py) on a custom page model exposes its pages through the api, which is great, however, when I try to apply a field filter, it is not applied, and the response returns all pages regardless. The [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/advanced_topics/api/v2/configuration.html#basic-configuration) has no mention of this.

for example:

endpoints.py

```
from wagtail.api.v2.endpoints import BaseAPIEndpoint
from app.models import MyPageClass

class MyPageClassAPIEndpoint(BaseAPIEndpoint):
    refname= MyPageClass
    model = refname
```

api.py:

```
from wagtail.api.v2.router import WagtailAPIRouter
from .endpoints import MyPageClassAPIEndpoint

# Create the router. "wagtailapi" is the URL namespace
api_router = WagtailAPIRouter('wagtailapi')
api_router.register_endpoint('refname', MyPageClassAPIEndpoint)
```

If i try to add a filter when i call my endpoint:

> http://localhost:8000/api/v2/refname/?id=6

the repsonse will return all the records associated to my model.

```
{
"meta": {
    "total_count": 2
},
"items": [
    {
        "id": 6,
        "meta": {
            "type": "app.MyPageClass",
            "detail_url": "http://localhost/api/v2/pages/6/"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "meta": {
            "type": "app.MyPageClass",
            "detail_url": "http://localhost/api/v2/pages/7/"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve filtering on my endpoint while extending the BaseAPIEndpoint class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to import the `FieldsFilter` Class from `wagtail.api.v2.filters` and then append it to the `filter_backends` of your custom endpoint's Class as follows:

```
from wagtail.api.v2.endpoints import BaseAPIEndpoint
from wagtail.api.v2.filters import FieldsFilter
from app.models import MyPageClass

class MyPageClass(BaseAPIEndpoint):
    refname= MyPageClass
    model = refname
    BaseAPIEndpoint.filter_backends.append(FieldsFilter)
```

After doing so, your endpoint will now accept filtering on fields.

> http://localhost:8000/api/v2/refname/?id=6

```
{
"meta": {
    "total_count": 1
},
"items": [
    {
        "id": 6,
        "meta": {
            "type": "projects.ProjectTaskPage",
            "detail_url": "http://localhost/api/v2/pages/6/"
        }
    }
  ]

}
```